# Постановка знаков препинания: двоеточие; запятая и тире

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

**Прекрасны свет и тишина лабораторий: как хороший ныряльщик скользит сквозь воду с открытыми глазами, так, не напрягая век, глядит физиолог на дно микроскопа, и медленно начинают багроветь его шея и лоб, — и он говорит, оторвавшись от трубки: «Все найдено».**
[**В.Набоков, "Подвиг", гл. XVI**](https://unotices.com/book.php?id=55302&page=12)

В этом предложении я допустил две ошибки.
1. Почему после "лабораторий" двоеточие?
2. Почему после "лоб" не просто запятая, а запятая + тире?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо сказать, предложение не для среднего школьника.

С двоеточием всё ясно: бессоюзное сложное предложение, вторая часть раскрывает смысл первой.

*Прекрасны свет и тишина лабораторий*: ...

а дальше то, что происходит в научной лаборатории по представлениям героя.

А вот запятая и тире поставлены здесь как единый знак препинания. В 19 веке его ставили часто в сложносочинённом предложении, а это текст Набокова - большого эстета и знатока русского языка. Сейчас этот знак ставят в сложноподчинённом предложении и периоде для обозначения паузы, распадения большого предложения на две части. В этом предложении как раз есть это распадение:

*...как хороший ныряльщик скользит сквозь воду с открытыми глазами, так, не напрягая век, глядит физиолог на дно микроскопа, и медленно начинают багроветь его шея и лоб*- это то, что происходит с учёным до совершения открытия.

*и он говорит, оторвавшись от трубки: «Все найдено»...* - констатация факта открытия.

http://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/114/

Так что все знаки поставлены по правилам, но в школе не говорят о запятой и тире как едином знаке препинания, поэтому за ошибку счесть не должны, можно было поставить запятую или тире на Ваш выбор.